# Visual Basic - Not Overwriting a Text File

Tags: vb.net, file, overwrite

I am writing a program where the user will be given a score and a name, and the two need to be saved in memory, then to be displayed in a listbox. Example:
Peter Paul 2000

With this in mind, the data cannot be overwritten. Example:
Peter Paul 2000
Peter John 195
Peter Jack 2301
Peter Best 7841

And then displayed from Highest to smallest.

Any Ideas?

Current Coded used in program to write and read the file:

```
Private Sub OpenButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenButton.Click
    Dim CountInteger As Integer
    Dim InStreamReader As New StreamReader("LeaderBoard.txt", False)
    ScoreListBox.Items.Clear()
    Do Until InStreamReader.Peek = -1
        InStreamReader.ReadLine()
        CountInteger += 1
    Loop
    InStreamReader.Close()
    CountInteger -= 1 'need ubound not size
    Dim InNewStreamReader As New StreamReader("LeaderBoard.txt", False)
    Dim DataArray(CountInteger) As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(DataArray)
        DataArray(i) = InNewStreamReader.ReadLine()
        ScoreListBox.Items.Add(DataArray(i))
    Next
    InNewStreamReader.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveButton.Click
    Dim ResultDialogResult As DialogResult
    Dim LineString As String
    Dim InStreamReader As StreamReader
    Dim OutStreamWriter As StreamWriter

    With SaveFileDialog1
        .InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath
        ResultDialogResult = .ShowDialog
        If ResultDialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        OutStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(.FileName)
    End With


    With OpenFileDialog1
        .DefaultExt = "txt"
        .Filter = "Text documents (*.txt)|*.txt"
        ResultDialogResult = .ShowDialog
        InStreamReader = New StreamReader(.FileName)
        Do Until InStreamReader.Peek = -1
            LineString = InStreamReader.ReadLine
            OutStreamWriter.WriteLine(LineString)
        Loop
        InStreamReader.Close()
        OutStreamWriter.Close()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess you need to buffer the old contents into your program

Comment: You might find [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) more useful than opening the file *twice* and manually iterating through it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Care to give an example with my code?

Comment: I just started programming a few months ago.... So Im brand new to this..

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file like this:

```
  OutStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(.FileName, true)
```

You will append to the file if it exists

This method would append a string inStr to a file fileName

```
  Public sub saveTofile(string inStr, string fileName)

      OutStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileName, true)
      OutStreamWriter.WriteLine(inString)
      OutStreamWriter.Close()
  End Sub
```

Beware of sintax errors, I can't try the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will fix your issue but as best practise you should wrap your `Streamreader`s (and `Streamwriter`s) in a [`Using` Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) block to ensure that the object is disposed of. For example re-writing the OpenButton:

```
Private Sub OpenButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenButton.Click
    Dim CountInteger As Integer
    Using InStreamReader As New StreamReader("LeaderBoard.txt", False)
        ScoreListBox.Items.Clear()
        Do Until InStreamReader.Peek = -1
            InStreamReader.ReadLine()
            CountInteger += 1
        Loop
        InStreamReader.Close()
    End Using
    CountInteger -= 1 'need ubound not size
    Using InNewStreamReader As New StreamReader("LeaderBoard.txt", False)
        Dim DataArray(CountInteger) As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(DataArray)
            DataArray(i) = InNewStreamReader.ReadLine()
            ScoreListBox.Items.Add(DataArray(i))
        Next
        InNewStreamReader.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

The same goes for the SaveButton

You should do this (whenever possible) for any object that implements [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.idisposable.aspx)

Comment: it still seems to be over writing the content of file every time.